# Fill Google chart after multiple async loop

Tags: loops, asynchronous

I have a javascript loop that has async PHP calls, retrieving data from a database:

```
var dueCount = {};
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {

    //ASYNC TASK #1
    getTaskDueNum(i, function(result){
        dueCount[i] = result;

    });

    //ASYNC TASK #2
    getTaskCompleteNum(i, function(result){
        completeCount[i] = result;

    });

}
```

The PHP looks like this:

```
function getTaskDueNum(var, callback){

var request = $.ajax({
    url: phpRoot + "get_due.php",
    type: "post",
    async: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        'var': var
    },
    success: function (data) { // <-- note the parameter here, not in your code
        callback(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
    }

});

}
```

After the data is retrieved, I want to fill a Google chart with it:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

However, the chart is being drawn prior to the data being returned from the async calls that fill dueCount.

How can I tell the drawChart to wait for the async tasks to finish?

Comment: Give a bit more information. It looks like your code is JavaScript... do you use any frameworks on your page (e.g. jQuery, Angular)? How does your getTask...Num() functions look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getTaskDueNum() function you show is actually JavaScript, using jQuery for the async bit. The AJAX functions all return a deferred object, you could pass them into $.when() in an array:

```
var deferreds = [];
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    deferreds.push(getTaskDueNum(i, function(result){
        dueCount[i] = result;
    }));
    deferreds.push(getTaskCompleteNum(i, function(result){
        completeCount[i] = result;
    }));
}

$.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
    // draw chart
});
```

You should have the getTask functions return the deferreds though for this to work (the variable you call 'request').

But maybe you should look at why you have to do 10 different async calls to a server instead of doing one and let the server combine the data that you need.

Comment: While the solution you provided did work, in the end I took your advice and  gathered the data on the server side.